# How shorten if something is null comprobation

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm not very experienced with C# and programming in general, but I think there must be something to avoid write things like this:

```
                if (item.Graf != null)
                {
                    item.Graf.IsVisible = true;
                }
                if (item.GrafReal != null)
                {
                    item.GrafReal.IsVisible = true;
                }
                if (item.GrafIm != null)
                {
                    item.GrafIm.IsVisible = true;
                }
```

Etc. I know there is something called lazy initialization, but I really don't need to create a new item, just check if it exists, in order to change its property `IsVisible`. If I don't check its existance (and it doesn't exist) I get a `Null Reference Expection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce an anonymous (or named) method, but I would not say it will improve the code (much), it depends on the number of such elements you have:

```
Action<GrafBase> setVisibleIfNotNull = delegate(GrafBase graf)
{
    if (graf != null)
        graf.IsVisible = true;
};
setVisibleIfNotNull(item.Graf);
setVisibleIfNotNull(item.GrafReal);
setVisibleIfNotNull(item.GrafIm);
```